# Simple API JSON result

Tags: php, json, api

i don't want to numbers on JSON ("1" "2" "3"...) i want the result result like when i use 0 on url :

When I use 0 on url he give me the first 4 items :
[image: when I use 0]

When i use 1 he give me the second 4 items but on result i see 1 2 3 4 i don't know why i want to remove them :
[image: when i use 1 or 1+]

this is the fonction 
fonction.php :

```
<?php
require 'connexion.php';
function getAll($x)
{
    global $connexion;
    $sql = "SELECT id_Article,Reference,Designation,PVTTC FROM bms_op_article where Designation like '%$x%' or Reference like '%$x%' ";
    $result = $connexion->query($sql);
    $res = array();
    $i=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $res[$i]=$row;
      $i++;
    }
    return $res;
}

function fort($x,$y)
{
    $tab=getAll($x);
    $tab1=array();
    if(2>sizeOf($tab))
    {$tab1[0]=$tab[sizeOf($tab)-1];}    
    else if($y>sizeOf($tab)-4)
    {
     return false;
    }
    else
    for($i=$y;$i<$y+4;$i++)
    {
        $tab1[$i]=$tab[$i];
    }
    return $tab1;

}
?>
```

this is the call 
index.php :

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'fonction.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/article/{var}/{var1}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $newresponce=$response->withJson(fort($args['var'],$args['var1']));
    return $newresponce;
});

$app->run();
```

i want to make them all like when i use 0

Comment: You aren't hiding anything.  You are returning 2 different JSON structures.  For some unknown reason your code manipulates the php arrays which are then json_encode() and returned.  In the code there are a bunch of magic numbers with no explanation of what they are.  If you don't want the behavior caused by the url parameter being > 0, then why do you have this code?  Just remove it?

Comment: i want all result be like the first one i don't know why numbers show when i use 1 or 2 or + i want all results like 0 that's all this is my problem

Comment: In the `fort` function try changing `return $tab1;` to `return array_values($tab1);` to ensure that returned array is indexed "properly" (properly as in a non-associative array)